# How do I turn off exceptions in a Rack app?

Tags: ruby, rack

I'm ready to deploy a RackServerPages application but can't seem to find a way to disable exceptions i.e, the one rendered by Rack::ShowExceptions.

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you don't have it in your Rack stack in production mode.

Comment: That's certainly an option but isn't there a way I can just turn it off in config.ru?

Comment: @matt try `curl -XINVALID -k https://my-app.com` it's a default rack stack trace middleware

Answer (score 4):

Set the `RACK_ENV` environment variable to `deployment`.

Technically, setting `ENV['RACK_ENV']` to anything besides `development` will disable the exceptions. `Rack::ShowExceptions` middleware is [included by default](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb#L157-L162) when rack is running in the [default `development` environment](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb#L194).

For Rails apps, set `ENV['RACK_ENV']` to `deployment`, making sure you also set `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` to the correct value for your environment (`production`, `development`, etc.). If `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` is not set, the Rails app will fallback to `ENV['RACK_ENV']` and Rails will complain about an unknown `deployment` environment.

If you use `unicorn`, you can alternatively [use `-E deployment`](https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/544167c5c3aec5993928634c084ae9dd8650be38/bin/unicorn#L56-L59) to set `ENV['RACK_ENV']` to `deployment`.

Answer (score 1):

I have several hour unpleasant experience of unsuccessfully trying to disable `Rack::ShowExceptions` but in the end I discovered I don't need to do that.

In production this is turned off (when you try to `curl -XINVALID -k https://my-production-app.com` it will return just blank screen).

But this won't solve the issue if you need to disable this in custom  (e.g. "staging") environment (still showing the rack trace code.)

tested on Rails `3.2.21`

on  Rails `4.0.12`  this works for my production and custom "staging" environment

Answer (score 0):

As `ENV['RACK_ENV']` is the universal Rack solution, Rack-based framework often have higher level solutions.

### Examples

#### Sinatra

In the `config.rb` it is possible to define [`:environment`](https://sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#environment---configurationdeployment-environment). It is also possible to use `ENV['APP_ENV']`.

```rb
configure do
  set :environment, :production
end
```

#### Roda

There is an [error handling plugin](https://roda.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Roda/RodaPlugins/ErrorHandler.html).

```rb
class App < Roda
  plugin :error_handler do |e|
    'Oh No!'
  end
end
```

And also an [environment](https://roda.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Roda/RodaPlugins/Environments.html) plugin.

```rb
class App < Roda
  plugin :environments

  self.environment = :production
end
```